# Given P ∨ ¬ P prove (P → Q) → ((¬ P → Q) → Q) by natural deduction

Tags: logic, proof

I am very new to proof and logic and I would really appreciate a rundown of this proof.

I use a program called Fitch to construct my proofs.

I understand there are two types of proofs. Direct Proofs and Case Proofs.

Please could someone be so kind as to walk me through both types using this example:

[image: Given P ∨ ¬ P prove (P → Q) → ((¬ P → Q) → Q)]

Following this I have deduced the following but I cannot post this as an answer yet as something doesn't check out.

Any advice why this might be. It seems to make logical sense to me to deduce ∨ elim from these sub-proofs.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! What have you tried yourself? Please [edit] your question to give your first steps and what specifically you don't understand.

Comment: @Keelan Thanks! My thinking is to break this up into cases i.e. subproofs. I am admittedly not that far into this. I am on line 4 but already at line 3 I am missing something and I just need a bit of guidance in the right direction.

Comment: so, perhaps you could share these lines (and the rest of the proof) so that we can really help you instead of just giving the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Keelan I've edited my question with a snapshot. I would prefer nudges in the right direction as oppose to just the answer. Appreciate the help.

Comment: thanks! I'm a little busy right now, but will pass by later today and write up an answer if there is none yet.

Comment: @Keelan Thanks. Will keep trying in the meanwhile.

Comment: Are you sure you rendered this correctly?  I believe this conclusion doesn't actually follow from that premise.

Comment: @ChrisSunami The conclusion I am trying to ultimately prove is P ∨ ¬ Q. I've scrapped the above and I've started again. Will post what I have shortly.

Comment: On closer examination, the premise is a tautology, it can be demonstrated with no premises. The conclusion is not a tautology, therefore, it cannot be proven from the premise.  Double check that you are working from the correct premise.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I am going to take a snapshot of the original question and edit the above with that.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I am so sorry... I posted the question the wrong way round!....

Comment: That makes a lot more sense!  Can you solve it yourself this way, or do you still need help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29040/discussion-between-tahlia-elcome-and-chris-sunami).

Comment: Skipping 2-10, step 17 is wrong; you cannot use 1 in the ∨-elimination of 13-16. If yo are working in classical logic, the proof of **(P → Q) → ((¬ P → Q) → Q)** "works" without assumptions, because it is a *tautology*.

Answer (score 7):

1) **P ∨ ¬ P** --- premise

2) **(P → Q)** --- assumed [a]

3) **(¬ P → Q)** --- assumed [b]

4) **P** --- assumed [c] for ∨-elimination

5) **Q** --- from 4 and 2 by →-elimination

6) **¬ P** --- assumed [d] for ∨-elimination

7) **Q** --- from 6 and 3 by →-elimination

8) **Q** --- from 4-5 and 6-7 by ∨-elimination, discharging [c] and [d]

> 9) **(P → Q) → ((¬ P → Q) → Q)** --- from 3, 2 and 8 by →-introduction twice, discharging [b] and [a]
>
> > **P ∨ ¬ P ⊢ (P → Q) → ((¬ P → Q) → Q)** --- from 1 and 9.

---

Side comment : the proof is *intuitionistically* valid. We can read it as : **if** we assume the *Law of Excluded Middle*, then the conclusion follows.

In *classical* logic the formula **(P → Q) → ((¬ P → Q) → Q)** is a *tautology*, and thus provable without assumptions; this is not possible with intuitionistic logic.

Comment: Many thanks. Your answer looks for easier than mine. Is this an example of a direct proof? I am going to post what I have but there is one mistake re my elim ∨ of a couple of subproofs which isn't checking out. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

My proof with Fitch: [image: https://gyazo.com/00858637c59c1ed8697cb48378dc7ae0]
Make sure you understand why I make the specific assumptions. Its important to understand why the proof follows, everytime you understand a new proof you aquire new tools to your "natural deduction toolkit".